# Pyspark - Aggregation on nested items with multiple conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using `Pyspark` and I have a dataframe with the following schema

```
 root
     |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

How can we add a new column named `short_chapters` that **calculate** for each book the Sum of NUMBER_PAGES for chapters with NAME.length < 10 ?

Note: we have a list of chapters, is there a way to iterate on without flatten the dataframe ?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: `pyspark= "==3.2.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute `short_chapters` using [`higher order functions`](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html). Find all chapters whose name has length < 10 using [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html?highlight=filter). Then add the `NUMBER_PAGES` for the chapters identified using [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", [Row(NAME="xs", NUMBER_PAGES=1),
                                   Row(NAME="s", NUMBER_PAGES=5),
                                   Row(NAME="Really Long Name", NUMBER_PAGES=100),
                                   Row(NAME="Really Long Name", NUMBER_PAGES=150), ],), ],
                           'struct<BOOK_ID:string,Chapters:array<struct<NAME:string,NUMBER_PAGES:int>>>')

df.printSchema()

"""
root
 |-- BOOK_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
"""

# Filter for short chapters
short_chapters = F.filter("Chapters", lambda x: F.length(x["NAME"]) < 10)

# Sum number of pages for short chapters
pages_in_short_chapter = F.aggregate(short_chapters, F.lit(0), lambda acc, x: acc + x["NUMBER_PAGES"])

df.withColumn("short_chapters", pages_in_short_chapter).show(truncate=False)

"""
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|BOOK_ID|Chapters                                                           |short_chapters|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|1      |[{xs, 1}, {s, 5}, {Really Long Name, 100}, {Really Long Name, 150}]|6             |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
"""
```

Comment: If instead of `sum` we need to retrieve the `min` how it would be changed ? thnks

Comment: @Smaillns you can change `acc + x["NUMBER_PAGES"]` to `F.least(acc , x["NUMBER_PAGES"])`

Comment: But how to initial the value ? maybe I have put `f.lit(MAX_SUGGESTED_NUMBER)` ?

Comment: @Smaillns you can initialize to the first page number. 

```pages_in_short_chapter = F.aggregate(short_chapters, short_chapters[0]["NUMBER_PAGES"], lambda acc, x: F.least(acc, x["NUMBER_PAGES"]))```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", [Row(NAME="xs", NUMBER_PAGES=1),
                                   Row(NAME="s", NUMBER_PAGES=5),
                                   Row(NAME="Really Long Name", NUMBER_PAGES=100),
                                   Row(NAME="Really Long Name", NUMBER_PAGES=150), ],), ],
                           'struct<BOOK_ID:string,Chapters:array<struct<NAME:string,NUMBER_PAGES:int>>>')

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- BOOK_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

**Solution**

Add a column on the StructType column and fill in with the required outcome.
For outcome chain user defined functions. First filter chapter numbers by a boolean selectio of chapter names whose length is less than 10. Aggregate the sum of page numbers filtered above. Code below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn(
    "Chapters",
    f.struct(
        f.col("Chapters"),
        f.lit(expr("aggregate(filter(Chapters.NUMBER_PAGES, (x, i) -> boolean(transform(Chapters.NAME,x->length(x)<10)[i])),0,(acc,x)->acc+x)")).alias("short_chapters")
    )
)
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- BOOK_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Chapters: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- short_chapters: integer (nullable = true)

df.show(truncate=False)

+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|BOOK_ID|Chapters                                                                |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |{[{xs, 1}, {s, 5}, {Really Long Name, 100}, {Really Long Name, 150}], 6}|
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.select('Chapters.*').show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|Chapters                                                           |short_chapters|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|[{xs, 1}, {s, 5}, {Really Long Name, 100}, {Really Long Name, 150}]|6             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a user defined functioned (short udf) that filters the chapter. The return type of the udf is the same as the **Chapters** column which we take using the schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def filter_short_chapters(chapters, thresh):
    return list(filter(lambda chapter: chapter.NUMBER_PAGES < thresh, chapters))

udf_fn = udf(filter_short_chapter, df.schema['Chapters'].dataType)
df = df.withColumn('short_chapters', udf_fn(df.Chapters, 10))
```